# Changing PS1 with conda

Tags: bash, conda, ps1

I want to change my prompt from `~ $`  to `~ >`  when activating `conda`.

I tried using `env_prompt:` in `.condarc` but it displays `> ~ $`  instead of the desired `~ >`  prompt.

(The conda prompt is preceded by the original PS1)

Can someone provide an example on how to implement this in my `.bashrc`?

Comment: Since Conda can't do this, consider adding a tag for the shell you use to invite responses from that sub-community. Or if you have an idea for how Conda could add such a feature, create a feature request on [the repository](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues).

Comment: @merv can you show how to do that in my bashrc?

Comment: This why I suggested you add a tag (`bash` if that’s what you want) and let others answer. My expertise is Conda, which I can readily answer about; for shell customization, I’m like everyone else and would have to look it up.

Answer (score 1):

Conda's `changeps1` functionality is limited to prepending a string to the shell's PS1. This string can be specified using the configuration variable `env_prompt` (as OP indicates). For completeness, here is how to query the documentation:

**env_prompt**

```bash
$ conda config --describe env_prompt
# # env_prompt (str)
# #   Template for prompt modification based on the active environment.
# #   Currently supported template variables are '{prefix}', '{name}', and
# #   '{default_env}'. '{prefix}' is the absolute path to the active
# #   environment. '{name}' is the basename of the active environment
# #   prefix. '{default_env}' holds the value of '{name}' if the active
# #   environment is a conda named environment ('-n' flag), or otherwise
# #   holds the value of '{prefix}'. Templating uses python's str.format()
# #   method.
# # 
# env_prompt: '({default_env}) '
```

To customize other aspects of PS1, one must do this independently of Conda. That is, you will need to consult the documentation for your shell (e.g., bash, zsh) or terminal.